# Default function parameter value visible in template but it shouldn't (gcc)

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer

Consider the code below:

```
#include <utility>

void f(int, int);
void g(int, int);

struct functor
{
    template<typename... T>
    void operator()(T&&... params)
    {
        return f(std::forward<T>(params)...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    functor()(1); // can use the default value here, why?!
    // g(1); // error here as expected, too few arguments
}

void f(int a, int b = 42) {}

void g(int a, int b = 24) {}
```

This is a thin wrapper around a function call. However, inside `functor::operator()`, `f` doesn't have its default value for the second parameter known (it is visible only after `main`, in the definition), so the code should not compile. g++5.2 compiles it successfully though, but clang++ spits out the expected message that one expects for compilers that perform the two-phase name lookup correctly:

> error: call to function 'f' that is neither visible in the
>         template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
>           return f(std::forward(params)...);

Is this a gcc bug or I am missing something here? I.e., is the point of instantiation after the definition of `f` below `main()`? But even in this case, it shouldn't work, as at the second phase the function can only be found via ADL, which is not the case here.

Comment: End of translation unit is also a valid point of instantiation.

Comment: Yes, but it still shouldn't work, since at the second phase only ADL is performed.

Comment: If instantiates at end of file, definition of `f` with default parameter is visible... Wonder if the program is not ill-formed...

Comment: @Jarod42 Ohh I see, yes I think you're right, since `f` itself was found before, and now the definition with the default param is visible. The definition is not other function, it's just the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[temp.dep.candidate]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.candidate):

> For a function call where the *postfix-expression* is a dependent name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup ([basic.lookup.unqual]), only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.
>
> **If the call** would be ill-formed or **would find a better match had the lookup within the associated namespaces
> considered all the function declarations with external linkage introduced in those namespaces in all translation units, not just considering those declarations found in the template definition and template instantiation
> contexts, then the program has undefined behavior.**

Note that ADL is not even working here, as the involved types are fundamental (their set of associated namespaces is empty).